# Printer keeps going down when BLTouch activates during auto homing (4.2.2 board)

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, bltouch

When I auto home my Ender 3 Pro, it does its usual thing where it goes to the corner and then comes to the middle. Although, when it goes down and the BLT activates, the nozzle keeps going down afterwards and hits the bed while the BLT is flashing blue and red.

I have tried swapping the terminals in which the BLT is placed and re-flashing the firmware yet it still doesn't work. I am using the 4.2.2 motherboard and I followed this video, [ENDER 3 / ENDER 3 PRO With Board 4.2.2 - How To UPDATE FIRMWARE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFRy_5lh2IQ&t), to make sure the controller and board were correct and this video, [How to install Marlin Firmware with BLtouch for your simple Creality printer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGyKCSWJYls)
, for the settings.

Here is the video for my problem: [3D Printer Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMyu-5eaviw).

If you need any more info, I will try to respond as soon as I can, thanks!

Comment: Hi Lionel and welcome. This SE site (but not all) has the ability to embed videos within the posts, see [YouTube video embedding has been ENABLED for this site](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/4762) for more info. I have taken the liberty to embed the video for you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the trigger signal (white) and GND (black) wires just had faulty connections.

Comment: Thanks for posting your own solution, please do not forget to accept your answer by clicking the checkmark in front of your answer. This may take 48 hours to self-accept your answer. Thanks! Happy printing!

Comment: How did you fix the faulty connections? Was it just a matter of pushing the plug in again, or did you have to do some rewiring?